# Back Navigate Button on universal windows 10 app

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

[RESOLVED] 
Need to add this Line :

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
```

[QUESTION]
I'm looking for a way to add a back navigate button at the top left corner of a windows 10 universal app running on PC. Why this is because on tablet and phone, there is a back button enable on windows, but when running the app on PC mode, there is no way to go back to last frame. Does anyone have a solution for this that looks like the button on the windows store app for example?

[image]

Comment: I find [this](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/handling-the-back-button-in-windows-10-uwp-apps). Hope it can help you.

Comment: Perfect, I add a response you can close your request ! Have a good day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a great example of the usage of the back-button : [here](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/handling-the-back-button-in-windows-10-uwp-apps)

You need this code :

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
```